# Grafana merge multiple counters values into one graph

Tags: python, flask, prometheus, grafana

I try to find a way to create an user counter with Prometheus and Grafana for my Flak app..

The Flask app run as wsgi with multiple workers and is also scaled via ngninx (docker scale). Because of this I create a counter with different labels. Where the labels is the hostname of the docker container.

The challenge that I now have is how to combine all of those counters into a single graph in Grafana.

In this example I have two processes with one having 5 and the other having 2 invokes.
Instead of having to two graphs I would like to see only one with having a final value of 7.

I tried to use **sum** for all values but that did not give me the desired graph.

Also tried **sum_over_time**  with **sum** but values are also not correct.

Using a sum without does also not solve it for me.

[image]

[image: sum]

[image]

[image]

sum without (worker) (irate(xxx_total[$__rate_interval]))
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [sum by / without](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators).

> `without` removes the listed labels from the result vector, while all other labels are preserved in the output.
>
> `by` does the opposite and drops labels that are not listed in the by
> clause, even if their label values are identical between all elements
> of the vector.

For your specific problem, it should be something like this :

```
sum without (worker) (xxx_total)
```

However, it seems like your counters don't add up correctly (probably because you execute your query between scrapes), so you need to first aggregate them individually over time using [sum_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time), and then sum them using `without`.
Like this :

```
sum without (worker) (sum_over_time(xxx_total[$__rate_interval]))
```

Comment: Thank you but that also does not help. I added the graph to the original post

Comment: no did not work. Added it to the post

Comment: it is the  same result like sum without (worker) (xxx_total)

Comment: That was looking better. I changed avg_over_time to sum_over_time and holy cow it works.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution is `sum without (worker)(sum_over_time(xxx_total[$__rate_interval]))`

Thank you to @kaios to pointing me into the right direction.

[image]